# Can setting Looper in a thread cause a java memory leak?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, memory-leaks

Lets say I have a thread defined like so:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    Looper someLooper;

    public void setLooper(Looper looper){
      someLooper= looper;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("MyThread - START "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
  System.out.println("mylooper:"+someLooper.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Now, let's say in the mainThread activity screen i do this:

```
MyThread t = new MyThread();
t.setLooper(Looper.getMainLooper());
t.start();
```

**Will this be a memory leak since the Looper is being referenced forever in the child thread** ? Will the GC be able to collect the memory from the mainThread activity or does it have to wait until the looper is freed? I think that it won't be a memory leak as the looper is associated with a thread, not a activity context. I need confirmation.

Comment: Whether an object is eligible for garbage collection is a function of who holds a reference to that object, not of which other objects the object in question holds references to.  Thus, the value of a `MyThread`'s `someLooper` member has no effect whatever on whether that thread is eligible for GC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main thread never ends as long as your app is running, so no it won't leak any memory.  There's no reference to Activity in Looper-  at least not directly (messages added to the Looper may have references to the Activity, but that's a different matter, and is only really a problem if they have a very long delay).